# Problema al insertar imagen en HTML

Tags: html

Estoy intentando poner una imagen en mi archivo de HTML y se me hace raro que no cargue mi imagen, solo aparece un icono pequeño en lugar de mi foto y no se porque si yo nunca habia tenido problemas al insertar mis imagenes, ya hice de todo, desde ponerle al final .jpg hasta cambiar el archivo de carpeta y aun asi no me carga la imagen, aqui les dejo mi código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nuevo.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <h1>
        Foto-booth
      </h1>

    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Mensajes</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <img src="02.jpg">

<p>hola</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

El problema no es que no aparezca la imagen, si aparece pero no carga, solo aparece un cuadrito chiquito como de 1 por 1px (ese cuadrito chiquito no es la imagen, es una imagen por default equis) no se porque no carga

Answer (score 1):

No carga la imagen porque tal vez no se encuentre en la carpeta raíz.

Si la tienes dentro de una carpeta prueba poner esto:

```
<img src="carpeta/02.jpg"/>
```

Si tu estructura es como esta el codigo anterior te funcionaria bien

```
-css
    -miestilo.css
-img
    -02.jpg
    -03.jpg
-index.html
```

Si tu archivo HTML esta dentro de una carpeta el código anterior no mostrara nada

```
-css
    -miestilo.css
-img
    -02.jpg
    -03.jpg
-vistas
    -index.html
```

por lo tanto el HTML que deberias poner es:

```
<img src="../img/02.jpg"/>
```

Los puntos `..` significan salir una carpeta pera acceder a img, tendrás que poner cuantos sean necesarios para llegar al directorio de la carpeta img

Comment: no la tengo dentro de una carpeta, la tengo dentro del apartado de imagenes en mi computadora y como quiera ya intente eso que me dijiste y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @RicardoA te refieres a que la tienes en las carpetas del sistema??

Comment: si, en la seccion de biblioteca y dentro de imagenes, si me explico?

Comment: @RicardoA ahi esta el problema, tendrías que mover esa imagen a la carpeta donde se encuentra tu archivo `index.html` por eso se muestra un cuadro con una x, porque no es encontrado en el "servidor"

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, incluso ya intente poniendo otra imagen con ruta absoluta en src y sigue apareciendo la imagen chiquita

Comment: @RicardoA espero que no hayas puesto algo así en el `src="C:\Users\tuUser\Pictures\02.jpg"` porque seguirá sin funcionar, o muéstrame que ruta pusistes

Comment: realiza la siguiente prueba, pega la imagen en la misma ruta de tu index.html.  deja el codigo original y dinos que ocurre. si aparece la imagen como te digo, es por que estas colocando mas la ruta.  saludos.

Comment: Estás definiendo alguna regla en el CSS que afecte a las imágenes?

Comment: asi es como escribí mi ruta ` <img src="02.jpg"/> ` ya  que mi imagen esta en la misma carpeta de mi index.html @JuanGlezz   @chenio  y no, no puse niingua regla en css que afecte la imagen @fredyfx lo unico que hice fue poner link cdn de bootstrap para css en mi head, eso cuenta?

Comment: Olvidenlo, ya pude resolverlo, el problema era que al momento de grabar los cambios en lugar de guardarse los cambios en mi mismo archivo se creo otro nuevo con todo identico y por lo tanto no podia ni con uno ni con otro, es una larga historia, muchas gracias por su ayuda!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Publicado por el OP en los [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15612/problema-al-insertar-imagen-en-html#comment25852_15614)

El problema era que al momento de grabar los cambios en lugar de guardarse los cambios en mi mismo archivo se creo otro nuevo con todo idéntico y por lo tanto no podía ni con uno ni con otro, es una larga historia.